# eAccelerator not working in xampp 1.8.0

Tags: apache, xampp, wamp, eaccelerator

from error log:

```
eAccelerator requires Zend Engine API version 220090626.
The Zend Engine API version 220100525 which is installed, is newer.
Contact eAccelerator at http://eaccelerator.net for a later version of eAccelerator.
```

from phpinfo()

```
System         Windows NT 6.1 build 7601 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Server Edition Service Pack 1) i586
Build Date     Jun 13 2012 21:17:57
Compiler       MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture   x86 
Server API     Apache 2.4 Handler Apache Lounge 
PHP Extension  Build     API20100525,TS,VC9
Debug Build    no
Thread Safety  enabled
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It seems like the error message says it all. What more can we add?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I do not know what to do ...

Comment: Do what we would have to do google around the subject. Basically you have to find out 1. If it is valid to run eAccelerator with Zend Engine. 2. if it is then find a precompiled dll somewhere that matcjes the Zend Engine requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eAccelerator not working because incompatibility with PHP 5.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Eaccelerator needs to be compiled for exactly the version of zend engine it is used with. You cannot copy a dll from any old installation into a new Php engine version. Eaccelerator is no longer maintained. Please check out "XCache" which is maintained and compatible with php up to 5.5.x:
http://xcache.lighttpd.net/